# eigenvectors and eigenvalues problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have solved an eigenvalue problem for matrix **A** which is orthogonal. I am trying to prove that the eigenvectors for matrix **B** is the same and find its eigenvalues. Matrix **B** is related to **A** as follows...

[image]

[image]

All I know is that the eigenvalues of **A^-1** are the inverse of eigenvalues of **A**. please help!

Comment: So is $x$ any column of $B$?

Comment: sean i have updated

Answer (score 0):

Based on my interpretation, here's how it goes.

Let $(\lambda, y)$ be an eigenpair of $A$ (that is, $Ay = \lambda y$). Then

\begin{align*}
By &= Ay + A^{-1} y + xIy \\
&= \lambda y + \frac{1}{\lambda} y + xy \\
&= \left( \lambda + \frac{1}{\lambda} + x \right) y
\end{align*}

and so $\left( \lambda + \frac{1}{\lambda} + x, y \right)$ is an eigenpair for $B$.

Comment: ah Ok, so y is your eigenvector. you initially state that it is an eigenvector of A, let B apply to it, and see what comes out?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.